# KeyError: 8 - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

On this method:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('order_picking')
@api.constrains('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    location = self.printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier.id
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_picking:
            for line in rec.order_picking:
                if line.qty > line.isbn.with_context({ 'location': location, }).qty_available >= 0:#line.isbn.qty_available in location:
                    rec.write({'state': 'awaitingraw'})
                else:
                    rec.write({'state': 'work_in_progress',})
```

It throws me this:

```
2017-12-14 01:50:15,732 5080 WARNING hasta_cuandooo_def openerp.models: method bsi.print.order.check_quantity: @constrains parameter 'order_picking.isbn' is not a field name
2017-12-14 01:50:16,075 5080 ERROR hasta_cuandooo_def openerp.http: 
Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1472, in check_quantity
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3789, in write
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 592, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4048, in _write
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5773, in recompute
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5773, in <dictcomp>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5654, in __getitem__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 841, in __get__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 6056, in __getitem__
KeyError: 8
```

The offending line is:

```
rec.write({'state': 'awaitingraw'})
```

This method checks for lines of products (isbn) to see if there's enough quantity, if not, it goes on `awaitingraw`, if there is enough, then it goes to `work_in_progress`. but it's very weird, the error comes after I added this method (before `check_quantity`):

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn', 'contract_worksheet', 'state')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if not len(record.transporter):
            raise Warning('Please Enter Transporter !')
        elif not len(record.transporter.transp_transit):
            raise Warning('Please assign transit account to the transporter !')
        if record.state in ('awaitingraw'): 
            record.temp = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles - record.contract_worksheet.total_totals
            acc_move = self.env['account.move'] 
            move_lines = [
                (0, 0, {
                    'name': 'name', 
                    'debit': record.temp or 0.0, 
                    'credit': 0, 
                    'account_id': record.transporter.transp_transit.id, 
                    'date': fields.Date.today(), #date,
                    'partner_id': record.transporter.id, # partner if there is one
                    #'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
                }),
                (0, 0, {
                    'name': 'name',
                    'debit': 0, 
                    'credit': record.contract_worksheet.total_alles or 0.0,
                    'account_id': record.transporter.transp_transit.id,
                    #'analytic_account_id': context.get('analytic_id', False),
                    'date': fields.Date.today(), #date,
                    'partner_id': record.transporter.id,
                    #'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
                })
            ]

            journal_id = False
            if record.transporter.transp_transit:
                journals = self.env['account.journal'].search([
                    ('default_debit_account_id', '=', record.transporter.transp_transit.id)
                ])
                if journals:
                    journal_id = journals[0].id
                    acc_move.create({
                    #'period_id': period_id, #Fiscal period
                        'journal_id': journal_id, 
                        'date': fields.Date.today(),
                        'state': 'draft',
                        'line_id': move_lines, 
                    })
            #return move.id
        elif record.state in ('work_in_progress'):
            record.temp2 = record.contract_worksheet.total_totals
        elif record.state in ('delivered'):
            record.transporter.transp_transit.debit = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles
```

Which seems to be working now, so, Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Also, when I try to edit the record, and edit the field `printer_book_block`, on save it throws:

```
         ValidateError

Error while validating constraint

              8
```

This is the field:

```
printer_book_block = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Printer Book Block")
```

**EDIT 2**

Seems like the problem is something between the `printer_book_block` which is a `Many2one` to `res.partner`, and the class id on which I'm working, the serial id it stores every time a new record is created, I saw this `8` as the id of the document, and same goes for whichever I try to edit,.

The error happens, and it just changes the number obviously, depending on which one I'm editing, very puzzling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to move this line inside the for loop and get the location from the `rec` not `self`.

```
     for rec in self:
            location = rec.printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier.id
```

Now i don't see the error here so of you comment the location and count available qantity in all location doe's this error still raise

Comment: Still the same problem :/ on the very same line,, let me try commenting it

Comment: try to remove the method and see if the method call is the problem? inspect and define what cause the problem use debug mode if you don't know how, i recommend that you learn how to use it

Comment: Yes, I'm using debug mode, the problem is defintely the rec.write, when it writes the state, Idk why, I've removed the location from the method, going to remove the method now

Comment: Okay, the problem is the account.move method, absolutely, why? No idea

Comment: Is there some other way to do an account.move? I'm looking for examples, not sure though

Comment: There's some misterious constraint on it, which doesn't let me do anything

Comment: the problem is that you are calling write in contstrains validation this is not good and you are creating account.move on a compute field this is not right, you should have a button to confirm your record with change the status and create account.move.

Comment: Okay, gonna try some other way now, and see what happens